# The cURL library hangs when retrieving a URL with D.

Tags: curl, d, libcurl

Using the following 'D' program on a Windows XP (sp3) machine with D 2.067:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.net.curl;
pragma(lib, "curl");

void main()
{
    writeln(get("ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates.html"));
}
```

The contents of the page are retrieved but the connection 'hangs', i.e., a command prompt is not returned. Any constructive suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just for reference, the above prints out the html and returns the prompt on linux (dmd `v2.067`), so it may be a system-specific problem.